# Implementation of SSRS reports in React.js or Angular js without SSRS authentication headers

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, reporting-services

I am working on removing the authentication headers or provide anonymous authentication for SSRS 2016. but i am using react.js and angularjs on a node.server

I have tried custom authentication methods in SSRS 2016 config files

I would like to be able to run SSRS 2016 reports in react.js and angularjs projects *without* being prompted for SSRS windows authentication username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unsuccessful in directly running SSRS 2016 reports in react.js without authentication headers.

However, I have created an IIS server with custom authentication where my SSRS 2016 runs on and I connected my react.js application to that IIS server